# Dynamic controls in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a problem where i need to iterate  dynamic form elements or control 
or in simple terms i need to repeat the form elements based on the for loop.

from the type script i have constructed array to  repeated elements, however in the 
html the values could not be listed for the options eg: **dropdown.dropdown1**

**drop down list value to populated in front end.**

```
dropdownList:[
  {
    "dropdown1": {
      "key": "1",
      "value": "dropdown1 value1"
    },
    "dropdown2": {
      "key": "1",
      "value": "dropdown2 value1"
    },
    "textbox1": "Y",
    "textbox2": "this is base value",
    "othertypes": {
      "othersubttypes": {
        "options": [
          {
            "key": "1",
            "value": "other types value1"
          },
          {
            "key": "2",
            "value": "other types value2"
          },
          {
            "key": "3",
            "value": "other types value3"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**UI HTML**

```
<div *ngFor="let dropdown of dropdownList">
    <div>
        <label id="dropdown11" i18n>dropdown1</label>
            <mat-input-container floatPlaceholder="never" id="dropdown11_container">
               <input  type="text" matInput  [matAutocomplete]="dropdown1" id="vdropdown1_Select"
               [modelOptions]="dropdown.dropdown1" placeholder="Select" displayProperty="value"  >
            </mat-input-container>
            <mat-autocomplete id="config_1" #dropdown1="matAutocomplete">
        </mat-autocomplete>
    </div>
</div>
```

**please refer to the pic.**

[image]

Comment: which `Angular` version you have use?

Comment: "@angular/cli": "^1.7.0",   and  "@angular/core@5.2.5"

Comment: can you create minimum reproduction using stackblitz

Comment: It can be done with dynamic form array

Comment: @PrashantPimpale could you share me some insight

Comment: @Gopal Do you want to create form Control as per JSON data?

Comment: @PrashantPimpale sorry for the update some how i have done yesterday i will share the solution in the thread